# python logging to terminal, redirect to workspace/file

Tags: python, logging, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I started tinkering with logging and BLE. Now I got this piece of code I took from the bgapi package. I think I kind of understand how it works, but I'd like to see the output in a file or in the workspace. How would I achieve this?

```
def pipe_logs_to_terminal(self, level=logging.INFO):
    term = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(self._api._serial.portstr + ': %(asctime)s - 
    %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    term.setFormatter(formatter)
    api_logger = logging.getLogger("bgapi")
    api_logger.addHandler(term)
    api_logger.setLevel(level=level)
```

Comment: change your stream handler `logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)` to a file instead of stdout. Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use `logging.FileHandler()`. I tried to implement it in your method:

```
def pipe_logs_to_terminal(self, level=logging.INFO):
    log_path = "."  # cwd
    file_name = "my_app"
    # configure root logger
    api_logger = logging.getLogger("bgapi")
    api_logger.setLevel(level=level)
    # set format
    formatter = logging.Formatter(self._api._serial.portstr + ': %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    # configure file handler
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler("{0}/{1}.log".format(log_path, file_name))
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    api_logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    # configure console handler
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    api_logger.addHandler(console_handler)
```

Optionally you could omit the `console_handler` (called `term` in your example) part, if you choose to only pipe your logging into a file.